# View is using original template rather than new custom template

Tags: views, theming

I have copied the views-view-grid.tpl.php file from the views module theme folder into my sites themes/my_theme/templates folder and renamed it views-view-grid--panel-pane.tpl.php, as was suggested in the 'Theme: Information' tab.  After a rescan and flushing of caches, the views-view-grid-panel-pane is bold in the tab, however, my changes are not reflected in the preview.  Am I missing a step?  I copy/pasted the file name, and triple check it, and it's bold, so I feel pretty confident that's not the issue.

Thank you

Comment: I wasn't seeing it because I was in 'admin mode' and I put it in the default theme directory instead.

Answer (score 1):

> After a rescan and flushing of caches, the views-view-grid-panel-pane
>   is bold in the tab, **however, my changes are not reflected in the
>   preview.**

The view's preview does not use template files from your custom theme. It uses the admin theme.

Thus, you can add the template files to your admin theme. The Drupal default admin theme is called "Seven".

Another option would be to just go directly to the view page url or where the view block gets displayed and just ignore your view preview.